# In my eclipse C++ ide, why can't string related functions be resolved?

Tags: c++, eclipse, string, ubuntu

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "!!!Hello World " << std::endl;
    std::string a = "aa";
    std::string b;
    b = "bb";
    std::string c = strcat(a,b);
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is "function 'strcat' could not be resolved". Also, other function regarding string operation such as `strcpy` and `strlen` cannot be resolved either. Since I already did

```
#include <string>
```

I don't know why this happens?

Comment: Those functions belong to `<cstring>`.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 0):

`strcat` is a C function that works on `char*`. You need `#include <string.h>` for it.

What you are doing is wrong anyway: You don't pass `std:string` parameters to `strcat`.

Use `c = a + b;`